# returning rxjs function of type Observable<void>

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to convert the below observable code from using Observable.create to using pipeable operators.

```
public getUnrecoveredGearsAfterDep(): Observable<void> {

    return Observable.create((observer) => {      

      this.vesselDetailService.getVessel().subscribe(
        (vessel: Vessel) => {          
          console.log(vessel.cfr);
          this.getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGears(vessel.cfr).subscribe(
            () => {              
              observer.next(null);
              observer.complete();
            },
            (error) => {
              observer.error(error);
            }
          );
        },
        (error) => {
          observer.error(error);          
        }
      );    

    });
  }
```

I've tried the below method but I'm getting an conversion error
cant convert type Observable.unknown to Observable.void
any help would be appreciated.

```
public altGetUnrecoveredGearsAfterDep(): Observable<void> {

    return this.vesselDetailService.getVessel().pipe(
      tap( (vessel: Vessel) => console.log(vessel.cfr)),
      switchMap((vessel: Vessel) => this.getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGears(vessel.cfr)),
      map((gears: GearSet[]) => of())      
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @bizzybob thats perfect, cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mapping your output to `of()` which is an observable.  This gives your function a return type of `Observable<Observable<never>>`.

Your map should simply return `undefined` or `null`, you don't need `of`:

```js
public altGetUnrecoveredGearsAfterDep(): Observable<void> {

    return this.vesselDetailService.getVessel().pipe(
      tap( (vessel: Vessel) => console.log(vessel.cfr)),
      switchMap((vessel: Vessel) => this.getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGears(vessel.cfr)),
      map((gears: GearSet[]) => undefined)      
    );
  }
```

Also, you could simplify by using [`mapTo`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mapto) and removing the type annotations:

```js
public altGetUnrecoveredGearsAfterDep(): Observable<void> {

    return this.vesselDetailService.getVessel().pipe(
      tap(vessel => console.log(vessel.cfr)),
      switchMap(vessel => this.getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGears(vessel.cfr)),
      mapTo(undefined)      
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end you are returning `of()`. The type of that value is `Observable<unknown>`, and it does not match the type in your return function  `Observable<void>`.

To solve this you can simply return `of(null)`.

Comment: `of(null)` will not compile hence `null` is not `void`.

Comment: It does compile?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-x7cnqx?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: Oh, I had `strictNullChecks: true` set in my TS compilet options. Nonetheless passing null is for "(naughty) devs" (quoted from rxjs/of.ts source code).

Comment: Lol, funny quote.  
Anyways good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could return it like that:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

public altGetUnrecoveredGearsAfterDep(): Observable<void> {
//...
    of(unit());
//...
}

function unit() {
  return void 0;
}
```

It worked for me in unit testing very well.